# Почему новый проект с React Hooks не работает на OS X?

Tags: reactjs, macos

Возможно, вопрос глупый, но решения я не нашел. Недавно перешел на мак и столкнулся со странной проблемой - React хуки в новых проектах не работают. useState, useEffect, useContext - not a function. Доходит до смешного - переношу проект с винды на мак - все работает, создаю точно такой же проект с теми же версиями библиотек на маке - not a function.
Что я делаю не так?
Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Версии такие или выше? `^16.7.0-alpha.0`

Comment: @DiDex, да, версия 16.7